# in Verilog on simulating the output equals zzzzzz

Tags: verilog

The code is very simple, having bunch of ifs to put a certain value in the variable BUS, the problem that on simulating, the BUS output equals : zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz 
while it's supposed to have certain values corresponding to the if case.

```
module Bus (AR_OUT, IR_OUT, DR_OUT, PC_OUT, AC_OUT, MEM_OUT, read, S, BUS);

 input [11:0]AR_OUT ;
 input [11:0]PC_OUT ;
 input [15:0]IR_OUT ;
 input [15:0]DR_OUT ;
 input [15:0]AC_OUT ;
 input [15:0]MEM_OUT ;
 input read ;
 input [2:0]S ;

 output [15:0]BUS ;

 reg [15:0]BUS ;
 // inputs are implicitly defined as wire


always @*
   begin

 if(S == 3'b001)
   BUS = AR_OUT;

 else if(S == 3'b010)
   BUS = PC_OUT;  

 else if(S == 3'b011)
   BUS = DR_OUT;

 else if(S == 3'b100)
   BUS = AC_OUT;

 else if(S == 3'b101)
   BUS = IR_OUT;

 else if( (S == 3'b111)&&(read == 1'b1) )
   BUS = MEM_OUT;

 else 
   BUS = 16'b 0000000000000000; 
 end

endmodule

module Bus_tb();

 reg [11:0]AR_OUT ;
 reg [11:0]PC_OUT ;
 reg [15:0]IR_OUT ;
 reg [15:0]DR_OUT ;
 reg [15:0]AC_OUT ;
 reg [15:0]MEM_OUT ;
 reg read ;
 reg [2:0]S ;

 wire [15:0]BUS ;

 initial begin

 AR_OUT = 12'b 0000_0000_1111 ;  
 PC_OUT = 12'b 0000_1111_0000 ;
 IR_OUT = 16'b 0000_0000_1111_0000 ;
 DR_OUT = 16'b 0000_0000_1111_1111 ;
 AC_OUT = 16'b 0000_1111_1111_0000 ;
 MEM_OUT = 16'b 1111_0000_1111_0000 ;

 S = 3'b 001 ;
 #10 S = 3'b 011;
 #10 S = 3'b 010;
 #10 S = 3'b 000;   // 
 #10 S = 3'b 101;
 #10 S = 3'b 100;
 #10 S = 3'b 111;
 #5 read = 1'b1;


 end
 endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Bus` module is not instantiated in the `Bus_tb` testbench. You need to instantiate an instance of `Bus` and hookup the ports.

E.g. :

`Bus u_bus( .BUS(BUS), ...);`

Answer (score 0):

why do you use module Bus_tb?why you don't use case structure? try this:

```
module Bus(AR_OUT, IR_OUT, DR_OUT, PC_OUT, AC_OUT, MEM_OUT, read, S, BUS);

 input [11:0]AR_OUT ;
 input [11:0]PC_OUT ;
 input [15:0]IR_OUT ;
 input [15:0]DR_OUT ;
 input [15:0]AC_OUT ;
 input [15:0]MEM_OUT ;
 input read ;
 input [2:0]S ;
 output [15:0]BUS ; 
 reg [15:0]BUS ;
 // inputs are implicitly defined as wire


always @(S or AR_OUT or IR_OUT or DR_OUT or PC_OUT or AC_OUT or MEM_OUT or read)
case(S)
1:BUS = AR_OUT;
2:BUS = PC_OUT;
3:BUS = DR_OUT;
4:BUS = AC_OUT;
5:BUS = IR_OUT;
7:if(read) BUS = MEM_OUT; //there is no state 6 in your code
default BUS = 16'b0000000000000000;
endcase

endmodule
```

Comment: the `_tb` module is intended as a wrapper which is used to drive the inputs in a simulator (_tb = testbench); it's a very common practice. A case statement is also a valid choice here, though be careful that you have an inferred latch on BUS (BUS retains old value when `S==7&&!read`), which is likely not what you want. It's  better as well to fully list out all cases and use the default case to assign `X`, or else your case will not propagate X and could hide design bugs.